# select every 4th saturday from a set date sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

I am trying to write a SQL statement that selects every 4th Saturday from a set date. So if the date chosen is 07/09/2014 then the query would return 05/10/2014 and 02/11/2014 and so on.

I can get it to select every Saturday going forward from the date but I can not work out how to get it to work out the 4th one each time.

```
SELECT DATE
          , DATENAME(DW,DATE) as Date
     FROM tblCalender
     WHERE DATENAME(DW,DATE) = 'Saturday'
          AND Date > '13-September-2014'
```

This is the select to get the saturdays going forward.

Comment: Show us the code you use to select the next saturday

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot loop and just add 28 days (DATEADD function) to the start date of the first saturday? Is 07/09/2014 = 7 Sept, 2014 as this is a Sunday.

Comment: @automatic added in the query now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it thanks to t_m suggestion

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = '19-July-2014'

SELECT  Date AS SatDate
          , DayOfWeek

 FROM (
SELECT DATE
          , DATENAME(DW,DATE) as DayOfWeek
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS rownum
     FROM tblCalender
     WHERE DATENAME(DW,DATE) = 'Saturday'
          AND Date > @Date
          ) AS t
          WHERE t.rownum % 4 = 0
```

Thanks for the tip!